How do I test whether an independent variable influences variable A but not variable B, taking into account my stimulus replication?
I have a mixed design that includes a two-level between-subjects factor and a repeated measures variable with four levels. The repeated measures variable represents a stimulus replication, meaning I am testing my hypothesis with four different target persons.
For each target person, I measure two variables (let's call them A and B). One of my exploratory hypotheses is that the independent variable will have an effect on variable A but not on variable B across all four target persons.
Which statistical analysis can I use to test this assumption, considering that I am assuming the null hypothesis for variable B?
Any help would be appreciated.

Your description is quite abstract, can you make your example more concrete?

Participants are randomly assigned to one of two conditions, type of description: abstract or concrete. Depending on the assigned condition, participants successively read abstract or concrete descriptions of four different target persons. After participants have read a description, they are asked to rate the target described in the description based on two variables (similarity & likability). I assumed that the manipulation affects the perceived similarity but not the perceived liking. However, how I can test this assumption is a mystery to me.

What is the rating scale? Likert, binary, continuous, something else?

Both variables are measured using a seven-point likert scale.
